# Preserving ICommand during Linking

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker, linker-errors

In my Xamarin.Forms code I use `ICommand` several times for creating hyperlinks.

The code works fine during debugging, but the command gets removed during release by the linker.

I created an XML file in the root of my Android project with its `Build Action` set to `LinkDescription`, that has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="System">
        <type fullname="System.Windows.Input.ICommand"></type>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

I expected that would preserve the command, but no; the links again don't work during release. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: things that get removed by the linker usually cause crashes, not silent failures.  Can you post an actual sample of how you are using `ICommand`?

Comment: Here is the **C# code**: `public ICommand OpenUrl => new Command<string>(async (url) => await Launcher.OpenAsync(url));` In my **XAML code** in a `TapGestureRecognizer` I have this attribute: `Command="{Binding OpenUrl}" CommandParameter="https://url"`

Everything works fine during debugging. In Release. If I set `Linking` to `None` the app runs fine too, but with `Linking` set to `Sdk and user assemblies` I have the issue I describe.

Comment: I also tried to build the app for Release setting the `Linking` to `Sdk Assemblies only`, **[but the build fails with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530782/linking-error-when-trying-to-build-xamarin-android-project)**, if I choose this setting.

Comment: I'd add some logging and exception handling in `OpenUrl`  to determine if it is actually executing or not while in Release mode.

Comment: It isn't. I have other `ICommand` instances in my code that call some methods instead of opening a URL. They also don't execute in "Release". It is also confirmed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484526/command-not-triggered-in-release-build)** that is the Linking that causes this behavior. As I said, also in my case setting it to `None` solves the problem, but results in a much larger apk file. My question is, have I implemented the XML file right? If yes, why does it get ignored?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the XML solution did not work, but here is what worked in my case:

Using the `[Preserve]` attribute before each `ICommand` had the desired effect during **Release**!

Answer (score 0):

You've got the wrong assembly. The easiest way to figure out the right assembly is to CTRL + Click the symbol `ICommand` in a Xamarin project, which will open a decompiler window with the assembly in a `#region` at the top of the file.

```cs
#region Assembly netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
// C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll
#endregion
```

Now change the XML to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="netstandard">
        <type fullname="System.Windows.Input.ICommand" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already solved the issue using the [Preserve] attribute, but your answer is indeed useful and explains why my XML didn't solve the problem.

Comment: If the solution helps consider marking it as answer .